# Black python formatter not working in zsh

Tags: python-3.x, python-black

I use the python formatter Black, but when I switched to zsh it stop working. Every time I try to use it manually through the terminal I get `zsh: command not found: black`

I have it installed here `/Users/HBrovell/Library/Python/3.7/bin/black` and added to my `.zshrc` with `export PATH="/Users/HBrovell/Library/Python/3.7/bin/black:$PATH"`

What I'm missing here to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't add `black` itself to the `PATH`; you add the directory *containing* `black`:

```
export PATH="/Users/HBrovell/Library/Python/3.7/bin/:$PATH"
```